# Xor of sum of all possible continuous subsequence of a long sequence

Tags: algorithm, xor

We are given a long sequence A1,A2,A3...An.We have to find sum of all possible continuous sub sequence and at last have to report xor of them.

**Constraints**:-N can be upto 10^5 and elements are less than 10^6 and positive.

My idea is naive O(n^2) algorithm and I can't come up with any faster one.I tried to notice any xor based pattern but can't guess any clue.Only Hint is required.

Comment: *Humbly asking* Why isn't there any reply to question ? I mean to say If it is not clear enough or I violated any stack overflow policy ?